# добавить класс ближайшему элементу к задействованному в событии vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

есть такая разметка:

```
<div class="item">
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <ul class="list"></ul>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <ul class="list"></ul>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <ul class="list"></ul>
 </div>
```

нужно при клике на title добавить класс к list

сейчас код выглядит так и он не работает, пожалуйста объясните что я делаю не так и как сделать правильно.

```
const names = document.querySelectorAll('.title');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.list');

 names.addEventListener('click', addClassActive);

function addClassActive(){
    items.classList.toggle('items-active');
}
```

Comment: Ошибка в том, что пытаешься обратиться к свойству `classList` *коллекции*, а у нее такого свойства нет (оно есть у отдельных DOM-объектов). Найти в обработчике клика первый (в данном случае - единственный) соседний `.list` можно выражением `const list = this.parentElement.querySelector('.list');` Далее - `if (list) list.classList.toggle('blabla'); `

Answer (score 1):

```js
const names = document.querySelectorAll('.title');
//const items = document.querySelectorAll('.list');

names.forEach(el=>el.addEventListener('click', addClassActive));

function addClassActive(){
    this.parentElement.lastElementChild.classList.toggle('items-active');
    //items.classList.toggle('items-active');
}
```

```css
.items-active {
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <h3 class="title">111</h3>
    <ul class="list">***</ul>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
    <h3 class="title">222</h3>
    <ul class="list">***</ul>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
    <h3 class="title">333</h3>
    <ul class="list">***</ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Еще можно вместо `this.parentElement.lastElementChild` просто `this.nextElementSibling`

Comment: @yar85 да, это короче будет, не подумал, бывает